# Alert mail for "Pending" column in List SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, office-365, alert

I'm using SharePoint 2013 online. I've created one List in which one Column is Choice (`Completed`, `Pending`) column named `Status`. For all Item If `Status` is Pending, weekly one mail should fire with List of only `Pending` Items as a alert to a person/group.

I think this is possible through SharePoint Designer 2013 but not sure how. Please provide steps if you have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a condition to check if the 'Status' is 'Pending' and send a e-mail with a workflow. See:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNxD82KiUhQ

You can use this powershell and create a task of windows to run the workflow weekly

```
$sourceWebURL = '<URL>'
$sourceListName = '<List Name>'
$TargetWorkflow = '<Workflow Name>'
$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]
$items = $spSourceList.getItems()

#-- Getting a Workflow manager object to work with.
$wfm = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($spSourceweb)
#-- Getting the subscriptions
$sub = $wfm.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()
#-- Getting the specific workflow within the list of subscriptions on the specific list. (SP2010 associated workflows basically)
$WF = $sub.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($spSourcelist.ID) | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "$TargetWorkflow"}
#-- Getting a Workflow instance in order to perform my commands.
$wfis=$wfm.GetWorkflowInstanceService()

Foreach($item in $items){
    #-- Creating the dictionary object I need to parse into StartWorkflow. This could be most other workflow commands.
    $object = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,object]'
    $object.Add("WorkflowStart", "StartWorkflow");
    $wfis.StartWorkflowOnListItem($WF, $item.ID, $object)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Diego, Here I'm need help how to fire consolidated single mail weekly basis for only Pending Items. For this scenario I'm getting stuck. Please provide the steps or link if you have some idea about this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Diego, But I've only access for SP Designer as I'm using Office 365 small.

Answer (score 1):

Would it work for you to create a View that shows the pending items and then create an Alert based on that view that will send weekly emails?

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14185.sharepoint-2010-use-alerts-and-views-to-send-selective-emails.aspx

Based on your comments, I am under the impression that you are trying to create a View using '[PO Date] is equal to 0'. If this is the case, you have a lot to learn about SharePoint I am afraid.

In any case, the filter should probably be '[Status] is equal to Pending' (or something to that effect). I do not see why you included the PO date in the filter (and based on your other question, the calculated field will eventually include the requirement for the PO Date too).

After you create the view, you will need to create the alert based on this view (Send Alerts for these Changes) and opt to receive weekly alert (When to Send Alerts).

Comment: Sorry the column type is Calculated not choice column. I've column "Name = Order Status","Type = Calculated"  & Data Type = "Date and Time". I've given this Condition in the column:-
=IF(NOT([PO Date]=0),"ORDERED","NOT ORDERED"). This is not a choice column as per your provided steps. I'm getting error while create the view "Filter Value is not in a supported date format". Please advice.

Comment: In your provided link the mail will fire when someone will change the item. But here in my requirement mail will fire automatic for all items which showing in "Pending" status as a alert to a person/group weekly basis. Hope this is clear.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a choice field or not. Can you create the view based on the criteria you want?

Moreover, if you set the alert to send a weekly summary it should get what you want. 

In any case, this is a straight out-of-the-box implementation. It may not be exactly what you need, but it could be close enough.

Comment: while creating view its showing error "Filter Value is not in a supported date format" however I follow the same steps which is provided in your above link

Comment: Yandr - I've column "Name = Order Status","Type = Calculated" & Data Type = "Date and Time". I've given this Condition in the formula:- =IF(NOT([PO Date]=0),"ORDERED","NOT ORDERED"). I'm trying to create view for this column but its getting error while create the view "Filter Value is not in a supported date format". 

Same error I'm getting for column "Name = Status","Type = Calculated" & Data Type = "Number". I've given this Condition in the formula:- =IF([PO Date]="","",IF(NOT([Balance Qty]=0),"OPEN","CLOSED"))

Comment: Yandr - As per your guide line I've created View for Not Ordered and set the alert based on your provided link. I set the alert to get weekly basis mail for Order Status = Not Ordered.
Change Type = All Changes, 
Send Alerts for these changes = Someone changes an item that appears in the following view
When to Send Alerts = Send a weekly summary. I'll update you the output soon. Thanks.

Comment: I hope it works for you. It would be the simplest, cleanest solution for your requirements.